# Ubuntu Hangs Suddenly (Dell Latitude E5530)

Tags: dell, freeze

I recently bought (a month ago) Dell Latitude E5530 which comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 11.10. I removed Ubuntu 11.10 and installed 12.04 LTS right after the purchase. Everything worked out of box but occasionally Ubuntu completely hangs. The screen freezes and I can't even switch to other terminals by pressing (CTRL+ALT+F*). Whenever the screen freezes, CPU fan speed also increases. This is not happening when running particular applications. I mean it can hang without giving any reason or error displayed and while running any application. In short currently I can't able to reproduce system hang myself. I also want to mention that sometimes it never hangs complete day.

Here are the specs of my laptop:

Processor: Core i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz

Memory: 8GB

HDD: 500GB, 7200rpm (Model=ST9500423AS)

Graphics: Intel HD 4000

Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit)

Thanks!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: You should try to install the latest 12.04.2 64 bits (LTS) (note the `.2`) which seems to be fine on my E5530.